# SQL identity phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I have some issue with very simple thing: IDENTITY. I'm try create table in phpMyAdmin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS typEventu (
    typEventu_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    typ VARCHAR(20),
);
```

**MySQL returned:**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IDENTITY(1,1)
>       typ VARCHAR(20) )' at line 2

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: You have a comma are the typ column. Also, mysql <> sql server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use SQL Server syntax for MySQL. Try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS typEventu (
    typEventu_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    typ VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. It's will be auto increment ID like IDENTITY(1,1)? I Mean from numer 1 and next +1?

Comment: @KonradRaj Yes, the default seed is 1 and increment is also 1.